# Is there a way to call a function on screen load with kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have a kivy program where I need the labels to populate with the data given from a function within my screen class. It works with the update button properly however I would also like for it to populate the labels on load. Here is the python file and the kv file:

py:

```
from kivy import *
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



class CurrentHighScores(Screen):
    highscore = None
    highscore_two = None
    highscore_three = None
    highscore_four = None
    highscore_five = None
    label_start_one = StringProperty(' ')
    label_start_two = StringProperty(' ')
    label_start_three = StringProperty(' ')
    label_start_four = StringProperty(' ')
    label_start_five = StringProperty(' ')

    def speed_scraper(self):

        URL = 'http://algoodspeeders.org/alpr/speederid.php'

        headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"}

        page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

        indexes = [3, 5]
        speed_data = []

        for tbody in soup.findAll('tbody'):
            for tr in tbody.findAll('tr'):
                speed_values = [td.text for td in tr.findAll('td')]
                speed_vals = [speed_values[x] for x in indexes]
                speed_data.append(speed_vals)

        speed_data.sort(reverse=True)
        # print(speed_data[0:5])

        self.highscore = speed_data[0]
        self.highscore_two = speed_data[1]
        self.highscore_three = speed_data[2]
        self.highscore_four = speed_data[3]
        self.highscore_five = speed_data[4]

        self.ids.high_one.text = '1st: ' + str(self.highscore[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(
            self.highscore[1])
        self.ids.high_two.text = '2nd: ' + str(self.highscore_two[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(
            self.highscore_two[1])
        self.ids.high_three.text = '3rd: ' + str(self.highscore_three[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(
            self.highscore_three[1])
        self.ids.high_four.text = '4th: ' + str(self.highscore_four[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(
            self.highscore_four[1])
        self.ids.high_five.text = '5th: ' + str(self.highscore_five[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(
            self.highscore_five[1])

        print('High Scores List')
        print('----------------')
        print('1st: ' + str(self.highscore[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(self.highscore[1]))
        print('2nd: ' + str(self.highscore_two[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(self.highscore_two[1]))
        print('3rd: ' + str(self.highscore_three[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(self.highscore_three[1]))
        print('4th: ' + str(self.highscore_four[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(self.highscore_four[1]))
        print('5th: ' + str(self.highscore_five[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(self.highscore_five[1]))


class ScreenManage(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('algoodspeed.kv')


class AlgoodSpeedApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AlgoodSpeedApp().run()
```

.kv:

```
ScreenManage:
    CurrentHighScores:

<CurrentHighScores>
    name: 'CurrentHighScores'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            name: 'current_high_scores'
            text: 'Current High Speeds For Cooper Rd:'
            font_size: 30

        Label:
            id: high_one
            text: root.label_start_one
        Label:
            id: high_two
            text: root.label_start_two
        Label:
            id: high_three
            text: root.label_start_three
        Label:
            id: high_four
            text: root.label_start_four
        Label:
            id: high_five
            text: root.label_start_five

        Button:
            id: update
            text: 'Update Current High Speeds'
            on_release:
                root.speed_scraper()
```

I have tried using things like clock to delay the function call outside of the class but that doesn't help at all. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried the tried working with the `on_enter` or `on_pre_enter` functions that are part of the `Screen` class by default?

Comment: no I haven't. I haven't even seen those. I will give them a look see. Thank you

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Will post my result in an answer below

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to a comment on my question I did some more research and reworked the code slightly and this were my findings for anyone else who is having this issue. I use on_pre_enter to call my function and within the function simply update the "label" variables I have to change the text within the kv file. Here is how it looks. I left some of the old code in but commented it out so you can see kind of how it looked before:

.py:

```
from kivy import *
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class CurrentHighScores(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        self.speed_scraper()

    highscore = None
    highscore_two = None
    highscore_three = None
    highscore_four = None
    highscore_five = None


    label_start_one = StringProperty(' ')
    label_start_two = StringProperty(' ')
    label_start_three = StringProperty(' ')
    label_start_four = StringProperty(' ')
    label_start_five = StringProperty(' ')

    def speed_scraper(self):


        URL = 'http://algoodspeeders.org/alpr/speederid.php'

        headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"}

        page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

        indexes = [3, 5]
        speed_data = []

        for tbody in soup.findAll('tbody'):
            for tr in tbody.findAll('tr'):
                speed_values = [td.text for td in tr.findAll('td')]
                speed_vals = [speed_values[x] for x in indexes]
                speed_data.append(speed_vals)

        speed_data.sort(reverse=True)
        # print(speed_data[0:5])

        self.highscore = speed_data[0]
        self.highscore_two = speed_data[1]
        self.highscore_three = speed_data[2]
        self.highscore_four = speed_data[3]
        self.highscore_five = speed_data[4]

        self.label_start_one = ('1st: ' + str(self.highscore[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(
            self.highscore[1]))
        self.label_start_two = ('2nd: ' + str(self.highscore_two[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(
            self.highscore_two[1]))
        self.label_start_three = ('3rd: ' + str(self.highscore_three[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(
            self.highscore_three[1]))
        self.label_start_four = ('4th: ' + str(self.highscore_four[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(
            self.highscore_four[1]))
        self.label_start_five = ('5th: ' + str(self.highscore_five[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(
            self.highscore_five[1]))

        '''self.ids.high_one.text = '1st: ' + str(self.highscore[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(
            self.highscore[1])
        self.ids.high_two.text = '2nd: ' + str(self.highscore_two[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(
            self.highscore_two[1])
        self.ids.high_three.text = '3rd: ' + str(self.highscore_three[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(
            self.highscore_three[1])
        self.ids.high_four.text = '4th: ' + str(self.highscore_four[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(
            self.highscore_four[1])
        self.ids.high_five.text = '5th: ' + str(self.highscore_five[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(
            self.highscore_five[1])

        print('High Scores List')
        print('----------------')
        print('1st: ' + str(self.highscore[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(self.highscore[1]))
        print('2nd: ' + str(self.highscore_two[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(self.highscore_two[1]))
        print('3rd: ' + str(self.highscore_three[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(self.highscore_three[1]))
        print('4th: ' + str(self.highscore_four[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(self.highscore_four[1]))
        print('5th: ' + str(self.highscore_five[0]) + ' MPH | ' + 'License Plate No. ' + str(self.highscore_five[1]))
'''

class ScreenManage(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('algoodspeed.kv')


class AlgoodSpeedApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AlgoodSpeedApp().run()
```

.kv

```
ScreenManage:
    CurrentHighScores:

<CurrentHighScores>
    name: 'CurrentHighScores'
    on_enter: print('working')
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            name: 'current_high_scores'
            text: 'Current High Speeds For Cooper Rd:'
            font_size: 30

        Label:
            id: high_one
            text: root.label_start_one
        Label:
            id: high_two
            text: root.label_start_two
        Label:
            id: high_three
            text: root.label_start_three
        Label:
            id: high_four
            text: root.label_start_four
        Label:
            id: high_five
            text: root.label_start_five

        Button:
            id: update
            text: 'Update Current High Speeds'
            on_release:
                root.speed_scraper()
```